# query regarding attendance report sql server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a table tbl_student

```
s_id | name
-----+-------
   1 | peter
   2 | robert
   3 | stive
```

and a table tbl_attendance

```
id | s_id | status |   date
---+------+--------+----------
 1 |    1 |     p  | 5-16-2014
 2 |    2 |     p  | 5-16-2014
 3 |    3 |     a  | 5-16-2014
 4 |    1 |     p  | 5-17-2014
 5 |    2 |     a  | 5-17-2014
 6 |    3 |     a  | 5-17-2014
 7 |    1 |     p  | 5-18-2014
 8 |    2 |     a  | 5-18-2014
 9 |    3 |     p  | 5-18-2014
```

I want to show the results in this format

```
s_id | name   | 5-16-2014 | 5-17-2014 | 5-18-2014
   1 | peter  |         p |         p |         p
   2 | robert |         p |         a |         a
   3 | stive  |         a |         a |         p
```

The select should be based on:

- this week
- this month

If it's based on this week I want the 7 days of the current week in the result.
If it's based on this month I want the 30 days of current month in the result.

Thanks

Comment: Can you show what you've tried so far and where the query failed to deliver what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following and can use the same by changing a bit.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Student](
    [ID] [int] NULL,
    [Name] [varchar](50) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Attendance](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [S_ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Status] [char](1) NOT NULL,
    [Date] [datetime] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]

-- Inset values to the above tables.

DECLARE @Dates VARCHAR(MAX),
        @Sql VARCHAR(Max)
SELECT @Dates = stuff((select distinct ',['+ CONVERT(VARCHAR,Date,106) + ']' from Attendance for xml path('')),1,1,'')
SET @Sql = ';WITH T AS(SELECT S_ID, Status, Date FROM Attendance)SELECT * FROM T PIVOT(MAX(Status) FOR Date IN(' + @Dates + ')) As StatusSt'
EXEC(@Sql)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you say this is for an attendance report, I assume that you intend to format and display the data in some other tool, such as Excel, SSRS, or even a web page.

You have several problems to solve:

1. How to get just the dates you want, depending on the parameters that are specified (week vs. month)
2. How to pivot the data so that the dates are arranged horizontally across the page and the students' names vertically

The first is a matter of translating whatever value you're using to indicate week vs. month into a range of dates.  That shouldn't be too hard to do, but if you find it challenging, post another question.

The second is hard to do in SQL Server without the use of dynamic SQL (as Muthu shows) because the PIVOT statement requires that you know in advance what all the headers of your columns are going to be, and that you code those values directly into your SQL statement.

But it's very easy to do in SSRS or Excel.  (It's not that hard in ASP.NET, either, though you'd have to write code to do it.)  So I would recommend you do the pivoting in whatever environment you're going to do the formatting and such in.